# SQL Server Update query needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need SQL Server `Update` query without using a cursor or while loop on a table to update projected stock.

When `projectedStock < ReorderPoint` then add `OrderQuantity`

For example :

- ReorderPoint  1600
- OrderQuantity 1200

Sample data:

```
Date          ProjectedStock 
----------------------------
15/03/2017       125
16/03/2017      -172
17/03/2017      -172
18/03/2017      -796
19/03/2017      -796
20/03/2017     -1420
21/03/2017     -1717
```

Results needed:

```
Date    ProjectedStock
15/03/2017  1325
16/03/2017  2228
17/03/2017  2228
18/03/2017  1604
19/03/2017  1604
20/03/2017  2180
21/03/2017  1883
```

The code I've tried is:

```
update sku 
set projectedStock = case 
                        when projectedStock < ReorderPoint 
                           then projectedStock + OrderQuantity 
                     end
```

But all rows will be updated on the same time wish give a wrong calculated `projectedStock`.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You need to at least show an attempt.

Comment: Sorry Lexi . i tried that query but the problem is , all rows will be updated on the same time wish give a wrong calculated projectedStock. 
update sku
set projectedStock=case when projectedStock < ReorderPoint then 
        projectedStock + OrderQuantity 
          end

Comment: I will add that to your question for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to update `ProjectedStock` when `ProjectedStock < ReorderPoint`, here is the query.

```
UPDATE p
SET ProjectedStock = 
    CASE WHEN ProjectedStock < ReorderPoint 
         THEN ProjectedStock + OrderQuantity 
    ELSE ProjectedStock END
FROM <YourStockTable>
```

Please do some work before asking questions. Please also show what you have tried and what was not working.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(StockDate VARCHAR(20), Stock INT)
INSERT INTO @T 
VALUES  ('15/03/2017', 125),
    ('16/03/2017',  -172),
    ('17/03/2017',  -172),
    ('18/03/2017',  -796),
    ('19/03/2017',  -796),
    ('20/03/2017',  -1420),
    ('21/03/2017',  -1717),
    ('22/03/2017',  2001)

UPDATE @T
SET Stock = CASE WHEN Stock < 1600 THEN (((1600 - Stock) / 1200) + 1) * 1200 + Stock ELSE Stock End
```

Result

```
+-----------+------+
|StockDate  |Stock |
+-----------+------+
|15/03/2017 |2525  |
|16/03/2017 |2228  |
|17/03/2017 |2228  |
|18/03/2017 |1604  |
|19/03/2017 |1604  |
|20/03/2017 |2180  |
|21/03/2017 |1883  |
|22/03/2017 |2001  |
+-----------+------+
```